# Read specific sheet by name on import excel laravel

Tags: excel, laravel, file-upload, import, laravel-excel

I have an excel with multiple sheets but i only want read one sheet:
[image]

My problem is that i have multiple sheets, and they do not have the same order or the same number of pages. Then, i must identify the sheet by name on my import class ([laravel import](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/multiple-sheets.html)).

Here is my import class:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;

class ExecutedUPS implements WithMultipleSheets, WithEvents
{
    private $nameSheetUPS = "LMS - F";

    public function sheets(): array
    {
        $sheets = [];

        //doesn't work for me
        if($event->getSheet()->getTitle() === $this->nameSheetUPS){
            $sheets[] = new SheetUPS();
        }
        
        return $sheets;
    }
}
```

And here is my class "SheetUPS":

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class SheetUPS implements ToCollection
{
    /**
    * @param Collection $collection
    */
    public function collection(Collection $collection)
    {
        //this i know do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried selecting the sheet by name as the [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/multiple-sheets.html#selecting-sheets-by-worksheet-name) does?

```php
//class ExecutedUPS
public function sheets(): array
{
    return [
        'LMS - F' => new SheetUPS(),
    ];
}
```